# Docker Volume empty after it's created

Tags: docker, docker-volume

I have a simple Dockerfile

```
FROM alpine

RUN apk add --no-cache lsyncd

CMD ["ls", "-al", "/etc/lsyncd"]
```

I build the image and it works fine, it works fine if I run it like:

```
 docker run -i -t -P <NAME_OF_THE_IMAGE>
```

and I get the folder listing with the expected files, since the CMD does that.

If I tun it like:

```
 docker run -i -t -P -v /docker/dcm/tst:/etc/lsyncd <NAME_OF_THE_IMAGE>
```

It creates the "/docker/dcm/tst" folder which is empty and the ls command also returns empty.

If my understand is correct, if the folder "/docker/dcm/tst" on the local machine does not exist a new one will be created and the contents of the folder "/etc/lsyncd" will be copied in the new folder.

Is my understanding correct? What could be causing the issue that I'm seeing?

```
uname -a 

Linux docker 4.9.53-5.ph2-esx #1-photon SMP Thu Oct 26 02:44:24 UTC 2017 x86_64 Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2620 v3 @ 2.40GHz GenuineIntel GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Are you running `uname -a` in the docker container or in the host machine?

Comment: Named volumes vs host volumes (bind mounts) behave differently.

Comment: @juanlumn "uname -a" I ran it on the host machine - just to show the OS that I;m running docker on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Bind mount` is for that a file or directory on the host machine mounts into a container

Regarding `Mounting into a non-empty directory on the container`, it is saying like the below.

> If you bind-mount into a non-empty directory on the container, the directory’s existing contents are obscured by the bind mount.
>
> For detail refer [this](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/#mounting-into-a-non-empty-directory-on-the-container).

It means that `bind mount` will just overwrite contents in the container dir.

I think you have been confused with `volume` which will copy contents in the container dir into the `volume` when it creates the first time. However, you are using `bind mount` and it doesn't work like that.

Comment: You are 100% right. I tried with "docker run --mount source=lsyncd,destination=/etc/lsyncd -i -t -P dcm:latest" and a new volume is created and the files are there as expected. My scope is mainly to store the files in a specific folder. For example for "https://hub.docker.com/_/wordpress/" I have can use "docker run -e WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD=password -d --name wordpress --link wordpressdb:mysql -p 127.0.0.2:8080:80 -v "$PWD/html":/var/www/html  wordpress" and the "html" folder is created with the new files added. But I guess they have some further custom processing.

Answer (score 5):

Named volumes and host volumes behave differently. A host volume, aka bind mount, maps the directory into the container exactly as it exists on the host. There is no initialization process.

The named volumes support initializing the contents of the volume when that volume is empty on container startup. It will be initialized to the contents of the image at the selected location, including file/directory uid/gid and permissions.

To get a named volume with a host directory, you can define a named volume that is a bind mount using one of the below options:

```
  # create the volume in advance
  $ docker volume create --driver local \
      --opt type=none \
      --opt device=/home/user/test \
      --opt o=bind \
      test_vol

  # create on the fly with --mount
  $ docker run -it --rm \
    --mount type=volume,dst=/container/path,volume-driver=local,volume-opt=type=none,volume-opt=o=bind,volume-opt=device=/home/user/test \
    foo

  # inside a docker-compose file
  ...
  volumes:
    bind-test:
      driver: local
      driver_opts:
        type: none
        o: bind
        device: /home/user/test
```

There is one other behavior change that I know of with named volumes that point to a bind mount, docker will not create the directory if it doesn't exist. Instead the container creation will fail with the volume creation error.

Comment: Thanks @BMitch , I'm trying to get the same behavior as https://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-use-the-official-docker-wordpress-image/  so i can use `-v "$PWD/":/var/www/html`